# How to customize the color of the KDE task bar highlight when not selected?

Tags: kde, themes, customization, plasma-5

After I start an application from the task bar, the corresponding icon remains highlighted, with a dim, gray, vertical bar, which is barely visible. How can I change the color of that bar?

In System Settings > Colors  I found how to customize it when it is selected or hovered (under "Common Colors", "Focus Decoration" and "Hover Decoration"). But how about when the icon is neither selected nor hovered?
I would like to customize the color of the highlight (vertical bar) indicated in the screenshot below.

I am using KDE Plasma V 5.12.7, KDE Frameworks V 5.44.0, with the Breeze desktop theme.

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any way to customize what you want but the dark color schemes afford better contrast.